# PHP fetch_row limits the result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with the rows but for some reason it populates only 14 rows. I have around 800 rows in the db. Any ideas?

code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM translation ORDER BY id");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) and $property = mysqli_fetch_field($result))
  {    

    echo "<tr>";
   foreach($row as $column => $value) {
        // $column is column name 'englsih', 'spanish' etc.
        $name = $property->name;        

        echo "<td align='left' class='cell".$column."'>". $value . "</td>";             
    }    
    echo "<td><span class='edit_b'></span><span class='remove_b'></span></td></tr>";    
  }
  echo "</thead></table>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `translation` table has 14 columns?

The problem is this:

```
... and $property = mysqli_fetch_field($result) )
```

You are fetching information about the columns in your result-set - and not even using it - and as soon as you have passed the last column, this will return `false` and your loop will end.

Don't fetch information about the columns in the same loop as your main results loop.

Comment: I figured it out. I use it somewhere else and noticed that I don't use it in this loop...